# is there an equivalent sniffer to justniffer for windows?

Tags: linux, http, email, networking, sniffer

I use a really cool [sniffer](http://justniffer.sourceforge.net/) for logging all web and mail traffic from the network. It passively captures the traffic and log it in apache access log format.
So i am able to post process log for web navigation statistics (most visited hosts, content size, etc)

We use it also to create mail traffic, so that have been able to identify abnormal traffic caused by malicious software installed on PCs connected to LAN (spamming malware, etc).

The problem is that there is a version only for linux OS. but it is based on libpcap. so i supposed that since winpcap is window version on libpcap, maybe could be no very difficult to find a similar tool for a Window Server.

Can any body suggest me a similar tool for Windows?

Thanks

Comment: Voting to close as http://serverfault.com would be a better fit for this kind of question.

Answer (score 0):

Consider [cain and abel](http://www.oxid.it/cain.html), which has other good facilities as well.  The web site describes it as a "password recovery tool ... [that] allows easy recovery of various kind of passwords by sniffing the network, cracking encrypted passwords," and other means.  Its intended users are network admins, forensic professionals, and others who intend to use it ethically.